# Copy lines between two specific strings from one file and write it between two specific strings inside another file

Tags: python

I want to copy lines between two specific strings from one file and then write it to another file between the same two strings. Here is the code I have tried so far:

```
with open("verilog.v","r") as rf_VamsModel, open("verilog.sv", 'w+') as wf_sytemVerilogFile:
    copy = False
    write= False
    for vline in rf_VamsModel:
        if vline.strip() == "//Start of functional specification here":
            copy = True
        elif vline.strip() == "//End of functional specification here":
            copy = False
        elif copy:
            for svline in wf_sytemVerilogFile:
                if svline.strip() == "//Start of functional specification here":
                    write = True
                elif svline.strip() == "//End of functional specification here":
                    write = False
                elif write:
                    wf_sytemVerilogFile.write(vline)
```

But this doesn't work, write file verilog.sv is empty with no content. I tried append instead of write but it did not work either.

Also I want to modify the code so that when it finds the matching line in write file(write==True) then it ignores immediate empty lines after match and also any lines starting with comments(//) after the match  and then start appending all the matching lines until it finds a match when write==False.

Comment: You're reusing the variable `line` for both reading and writing.

Comment: in addition to the fact that you're overwriting your read `line` when you are scanning through your target file, `write()` just writes the argument at the file objects current position in the file, which is the very beginning of the file unless you've already written to it or used `seek()` to change the position.

Comment: I changed line to vline and svline now inside original post, but no change in the output. write file is empty.

Comment: I'm opening both file for first time. I thought for loop will increment file position as "svline" counter to write file is incremented?

Comment: any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it myself. 
This code can be used to copy lines between two specific strings/lines form one file to an another file. It writes those lines to an another file only if similar lines is already present inside write file:

```
with open("verilog.v","r") as rf_VamsModel:
    copy = False
    write= False
    for vline in rf_VamsModel:
        if vline.strip() == "//Start of functional specification here":
            copy = True
        elif vline.strip() == "//End of functional specification here":
            copy = False
        elif copy:
            wtstring=wtstring+vline #wtstring has the functional code between two lines which you want to write to .sv file

with open("verilog.sv", "r+") as wf_sytemVerilogFile:
    insert=False
    contents=wf_sytemVerilogFile.readlines()
    for index, svline in enumerate(contents):
        if svline.strip() == "//End of functional specification here":
            wtindex=index
            insert=True
            break
    contents.insert(wtindex,wtstring) #contents has complete code in list format, functional code is copied from VAMS model into SV model
    stringContents="".join(contents) #convert list into string in order to write it to .sv file
    if insert:
        wf_sytemVerilogFile.seek(0,0)
        wf_sytemVerilogFile.write(str(stringContents))
    else:
        print("did not write since insert==False")
```